# Замена shared_ptr на unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointer

Нужно заменить `shared_ptr` на unique_ptr, ибо первый не умеет работать с массивами. А `unique_ptr` не дает копировать себя. Что в этом случае делать?

```
**MatrixShape.hpp**  
#ifndef MATRIXSHAPE_HPP_INCLUDED
#define MATRIXSHAPE_HPP_INCLUDED
#include <memory>
#include "Shape.hpp"

class MatrixShape
{
public:
  MatrixShape(const std::shared_ptr<Shape> &);
  MatrixShape(const MatrixShape &);
  MatrixShape & operator=(const MatrixShape &);
  // HERE std::unique_ptr <std::shared_ptr<Shape>[]>::pointer operator[](const size_t &index) const; // HERE
  void addShape(const std::shared_ptr<Shape> &);
  void print() const;

private:
  std::unique_ptr <std::shared_ptr<Shape>[]> matrix_;
  size_t rows_, columns_;
  bool checkOverlap(const std::shared_ptr<Shape> &, const std::shared_ptr<Shape> &) const;
};

#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>
#include "MatrixShape.hpp"

MatrixShape::MatrixShape(const std::shared_ptr<Shape> &shape):
  matrix_(new std::shared_ptr<Shape>[1]),
  rows_(1),
  columns_(1)
{
  if (shape == nullptr)
  {
    throw std::invalid_argument("invalid pointer");
  }

  matrix_[0] = shape;
}

MatrixShape::MatrixShape(const MatrixShape &matrix_shape):
  rows_(matrix_shape.rows_),
  columns_(matrix_shape.columns_)
{
  std::unique_ptr <std::shared_ptr<Shape>[]> matrix_copy(new std::shared_ptr<Shape>[rows_ * columns_]);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < (rows_ * columns_); i ++)
  {
    matrix_copy[i] = matrix_shape.matrix_[i];
  }

  matrix_.swap(matrix_copy);
}

MatrixShape & MatrixShape::operator=(const MatrixShape &matrix_shape)
{
  if (this != &matrix_shape)
  {
    rows_ = matrix_shape.rows_;
    columns_ = matrix_shape.columns_;
    std::unique_ptr <std::shared_ptr<Shape>[]> matrix_copy(new std::shared_ptr<Shape>[rows_ * columns_]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (rows_ * columns_); i ++)
    {
      matrix_copy[i] = matrix_shape.matrix_[i];
    }

    matrix_.swap(matrix_copy);
  }

  return *this;
}

std::unique_ptr <std::shared_ptr<Shape>[]>::pointer MatrixShape::operator[](const size_t &index) const
{
  if (index > rows_)
  {
    throw std::invalid_argument("index out of range");
  }

  return matrix_.get() + index * columns_;
}

void MatrixShape::addShape(const std::shared_ptr<Shape> &shape)
{
  if (shape == nullptr)
  {
    throw std::invalid_argument("invalid pointer");
  }

  size_t i = rows_ * columns_;
  size_t desired_row = 1; 

  while (i > 0)
  {
    i --;

    if (checkOverlap(matrix_[i], shape))
    {
      desired_row = i / columns_ + 2;
    }
  }

  size_t rows_temp = rows_;
  size_t columns_temp = columns_;
  size_t free_columns = 0;

  if (desired_row > rows_)
  {
    rows_temp ++;
    free_columns = columns_;
  }
  else
  {
    size_t j = (desired_row - 1) * columns_;
    while (j < (desired_row * columns_))
    {
      if (matrix_[j] == nullptr)
      {
        free_columns ++;
      }

      j ++;
    }

    if (free_columns == 0)
    {
      columns_temp ++;
      free_columns = 1;
    }
  }

  std::unique_ptr <std::shared_ptr<Shape>[]> matrix_temp(new std::shared_ptr<Shape>[rows_temp * columns_temp]);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < rows_temp; i ++)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < columns_temp; j ++)
    {
      if (i >= rows_ || j >= columns_)
      {
        matrix_temp[i * columns_temp + j] = nullptr;
        continue;
      }

      matrix_temp[i * columns_temp + j] = matrix_[i * columns_ + j];
    }
  }

  matrix_temp[desired_row * columns_temp - free_columns] = shape;

  matrix_.swap(matrix_temp);
  rows_ = rows_temp;
  columns_ = columns_temp;
}

bool MatrixShape::checkOverlap(const std::shared_ptr<Shape> &shape_1, const std::shared_ptr<Shape> &shape_2) const
{
  if (shape_1 == nullptr || shape_2 == nullptr)
  {
    return false;
  }

  rectangle_t shape_1_frame_rect = shape_1 -> getFrameRect();
  rectangle_t shape_2_frame_rect = shape_2 -> getFrameRect();

  return ((fabs(shape_1_frame_rect.pos.x - shape_2_frame_rect.pos.x)
    < ((shape_1_frame_rect.width / 2) + (shape_2_frame_rect.width / 2)))
    && ((fabs(shape_1_frame_rect.pos.y - shape_2_frame_rect.pos.y)
    < ((shape_1_frame_rect.height / 2) + (shape_2_frame_rect.height / 2)))));
}

void MatrixShape::print() const
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < rows_; i ++)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < columns_; j ++)
    {
      if (matrix_[i * columns_ + j] != nullptr)
      {
        std::cout << std::setw(16) << std::left << matrix_[i * columns_ + j] -> getName();
      }
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Исключено, нужно именно использовать умные указатели.

Comment: Уберите из кода всё лишнее, оставьте только суть. Для справки: [mcve]. После этого можно будет поговорить предметно.

Comment: Не хотите использовать boost::shared_array ?

Answer (score 4):

**Не надо ничего заменять.**

Хоть `std::shared_ptr` и не поддерживает массивы в явном виде, мы можем обмануть его, передав указатель на начало массива так, будто это указатель на единственный элемент.

Ведь как работают умные указатели в C++? Они принимают указатель, над которым нужно установить владение, и *deleter* — функциональный объект, знающий, как корректно освободить данные по этому указателю.

Так как *указатель на массив* тождественен *указателю на первый элемент массива* (то есть эти два понятия взаимозаменяемые), то единственное, что нам остаётся — передать умному указателю *deleter*, работающий с массивами. Кстати, если вы выделяете массив оператором `new[]`, то нам подойдёт стандартный `std::default_delete<T[]>`.

Для удобства использования обернём создание массива в шаблонный метод:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> allocateArray(size_t n)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T[n], std::default_delete<T[]>());
}
```

У данного способа есть один недостаток — вам придётся где-то хранить размер массива.