# shared_ptr для динамического массива

Tags: c++

```
class My {
public:

    auto create(size_t size)->void;
    auto empty()->bool;
    auto print()->void;


    size_t size;
    shared_ptr<int> arr;
};

auto My::create(size_t size)->void {
    this->arr = make_shared<int>(new int[size]);
    this->size = size;
};
```

Имеется небольшой класс для создания массива обернутого в shared_ptr, при запуске возникает ошибка : "Невозможно преобразовать int* в int", не могу понять почему

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13794447/4928642

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/727928/178988 - похоже, есть такой вариант ещё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объединю решения вопроса для удобства: 
1) [ассоциация](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13794447/4928642) 
2) используя reset

```
 this->arr.reset(new int[size], std::default_delete<int[]>());
```

Comment: Ассоциация работает только в комментариях к вопросу. Вообще, ассоциации нужны для работы [одного дополнения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4409/208074), которое отображает под вопросами на англоязычном SO плашку со ссылкой на ассоциированные вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что [`make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) создаёт указатель на один объект, а параметры передаёт в конструктор. Т. е.

```
auto a = make_shared <int> (42);
```

это по сути представляет собой (хотя и немного эффективнее)

```
auto a = shared_ptr <int> (new int (42));
```

Похоже, что использовать для массивов его не удастся (что может быть вызвано различиями в выделении и освобождении памяти). Можно вместо массива использовать какой-нибудь класс, например, вектор.

Comment: идея с вектором хорошая, помогло решить проблему используя reset,
this->arr.reset(new int[size], std::default_delete<int[]>());

Comment: `Похоже, что использовать для массивов его не удастся` — я [уже отвечал на довольно похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/727928/208074), причём дал решение в том же ключе, что и автор вопроса комментарием выше.

Comment: @John, зачем сбрасывать массив? Разве нельзя его сразу создать с нужным *deleter*-ом, передав его в конструктор?

Answer (score 1):

`make_shared` будет (скорее всего) поддерживать создание `shared_ptr`, в котором хранится указатель на массив, со следующей версии C++. `shared_ptr` поддерживает такое создание уже сегодня, но для этого нужно иметь последний компилятор, поддерживающий этот функционал (студия на момент написания ответа этого не умеет).

```
this->arr = std::shared_ptr<int[]>(new int[size]);
```